# Delete /n at end of a String (Python)

Tags: python

How can I delete a `/n` linebreak at the end of a String ?

I´m trying to read two strings from an `.txt` file and want to format them with `os.path.join()` method after I "cleared" the string.

Here you can see my try with dummy data:

```
content = ['Source=C:\\Users\\app\n', 'Target=C:\\Apache24\\htdocs']

for string in content:
    print(string)
    if string.endswith('\\\n'):
        string = string[0:-2]

print(content)
```

Comment: I think you're trying to modify the iterator rather than the contents, besides this does what you want: `[x.rstrip('\n') for x in content]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not update a string like you are trying to. Python strings are immutable. Every time you change a string, new instance is created. But, your list still refers to the old object. So, you can create a new list to hold updated strings. And to strip newlines you can use `rstrip` function. Have a look at the code below,

```
content = ['Source=C:\\Users\\app\n', 'Target=C:\\Apache24\\htdocs']
updated = []
for string in content:
    print(string)
    updated.append(string.rstrip())

print(updated)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rstrip` function. it trims any 'empty' string including `\n` from the string, like below:

```
>>> a = "aaa\n"
>>> print a
aaa
>>> a.rstrip()
'aaa'
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove only `\n` use this:

```
string = string.rstrip('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `string[0:-2]` you are actually removing 2 characters from the end, while `\n` is one character.

try:

```
content = map(lambda x: x.strip(), content)
```